# Accessing methods of Observable class in Observer class

Tags: java, design-patterns, observers

How do you access a method/instance from an Observable class in an Observer class where the method/instance is not the object being observed.

For example, if these getter methods were in my Observable class but only book was being observed, how would I access name and store in my Observer class (namely in the update() method)?

```
public class MethodEx extends Observable {
        ...
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getBook(){
        return this.book;
    }

    public String getStore(){
        return this.store;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically pass the observed object along with the event. This is done in for instance [`ChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html) which uses a [`ChangeEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeEvent.html). The `ChangeEvent` has a `getSource` method that tells which object was changed.

Translated to your terminology, you would do

```
public String setBook(Book book) {
    this.book = book;
    for (UpdateListener listener : listeners)
        listener.updated(new UpdateEvent(this));
}
```

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this (like with less coding)?

Comment: You can skip the `UpdateEvent` class and just pass `this` to the `updated` method, but you can't pick up the changed object magically through the call stack or anything like that.